# Excel formula failing with "too many arguments"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm getting a message from Excel that my formula has too many arguments, but tutorials I've found regarding multiple IFs do follow this pattern.
My formula is:

```
=IF(F5="Credit", (E5*0.5), IF(F5="Debit", (E5*0.1)), IF(F5="Cash", (E5*0.2)), IF(F5="Adv.", (E5*0.1))
```

What I'm doing is asking the cell to check if "Credit, Debit, Cash or adv" text is on previous cell so it applies a specific percentage.

edit: Thanks Scott, helped a lot!

Answer (score 4):

The first rule of debugging Excel formulas is to check parentheses. 
Your expression has eight left parentheses, i.e., `(`,
and seven right parentheses, i.e., `)`. 
So it’s wrong.

The second rule of debugging Excel formulas is to check parentheses.

```
=IF(F5="Credit", (E5*0.5), IF(F5="Debit", (E5*0.1)), IF(F5="Cash", (E5*0.2)), IF(F5="Adv.", (E5*0.1))
    ↑---------↑  ↑------↑  ↑----------------------↑  ↑---------------------↑  ↑---------------------↑
```

You’re calling `IF` with five arguments. 
As you should know from the documentation you’ve read,
you call `IF` with three arguments: `IF(boolean, <value-if-true>, <value-if-false>)`. 
The trick is that *`<value-if-true>`* and *`<value-if-false>`*
can also be `IF` calls. 
It might help if you build the formula from the inside out.

Comment: This formula works with a little parentheses jiggleing. Basicly nest all of the If fucntions, and add enough parentheses on the end. 

=IF(F5="Credit",(E5*0.5),(IF(F5="Debit",(E5*0.1),(IF(F5="Cash",(E5*0.2),IF(F5="Adv.",(E5*0.1)))))))

Comment: ... which is essentially the same as [the other answer](https://superuser.com/q/1246644/150988#1246828), which was posted two days ago.  But you added more parentheses than needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing If with a lot of () and without the value if false, you have to move some ) to the end of the formula and at least write one value if false, when F5 is empty or different from all the values you wrote.
I corrected your formula and used "" for value if false it will return an empty cell:

```
=IF(F5="Credit", (E5*0.5), IF(F5="Debit", (E5*0.1), IF(F5="Cash", (E5*0.2), IF(F5="Adv.", (E5*0.1),""))))
```

For example:
IF(F5="Debit", (E5*0.1))
I moved the last ) to the end of the formula
You can take a look at [nested if function](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/nested-if.html)